# Приставка в слове ''смущаться''

Tags: морфемика

В словаре Потихи (1964) в слове "смутиться" приставка не выделяется. Смутиться от слова **смута**. В словаре Тихонова (онлайн-версия) есть существительное: **смущение,** приставка здесь выделяется.

Мне кажется логичным выделять приставку **с**. Ведь у него есть однокоренные слова как с другими приставками **(помутиться, возмутить)**, так и без них **(мутить)**.

Что вы думаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне так не кажется.

Мут/и/ть, по/мут/и/ть/ся, воз/мут/и/ть - родственные и сейчас, они связаны значением мутить-делать мутным, волновать, тревожить. От него - смут/а-мятеж, беспорядок.Сейчас приставка не выделяется.Значения  "мутный" и "смутный" тоже разошлись, хотя и сохраняют какую-то общность.

А вот смут/и/ть, смущ/а/ть, смущ/ени/е теперь имеют другой смысл, сводящийся к значению "замешательство,застенчивость, стыд", к "мутному" не относятся никак.

Comment: Людмила, а как же у Тихонова? Это ошибка?

Comment: А можно ли в одном слове выделять и не выделять  приставки в зависимости от значения? Омонимы не в счет.

Comment: Смутный и муторный. Кажется, эти слова не настолько расходятся по значению, что б говорить о разных корнях?

Comment: Серж, это не у Тихонова, это неизвестно, что за онлайн-версия. У меня Тихонов бумажный перед глазами, там слова вообще нет, это или домысливание составителями онлайн-словаря(в значении смущать - уводить от правильного пути, делать мутным), или работа робота,  морфемику по онлайн-словарям нельзя проверять, ошибок много. А значение слова имеет в мрфемике большое значение, иногда ведь слова ещё омонимами не стали, а мотивируются уже по-разному, просто кто-то уже относит к омонимам, кто-то нет.

Comment: Смутный - неясный, а муторный - одна муть. По-моему значения совсем разные, даже оценка у муторного - резко отрицательная. На душе смутно - неясно, непонятно, предчувствия нехорошие, а муторно - тошнит от мути, мутит, тревожит.

Comment: Людмила, у Тихонова (онлайн-версия) не ''смутиться'', а ''смущение''.  Вот ссылка на словарь: [Морфемно-орфографический словарь. — 2002](https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/)

Comment: Это задание из теста.

Comment: Это уже не его словарь, а доработанный родственниками по каким-то там технологиям. Слово даже искать не стала, со временем не очень, но что ему не доверяю -это точно, уже сталкивалась. А что за тесты? Сейчас вроде из ГИА и ЕГЭ всю морфемику убрали, потому что  нет единого взгляда в науке на морфемный состав, и это понятно.

Comment: Если честно, не знаю. Знаю одно: это тесты для абитуриентов.  Вопрос задали в одноклассниках в группе "Русский язык''. Версию, которую я написал в вопросе, предложила педагог со стажем. Честно говоря я тоже так думал. Но вижу, Вы правы.